# Is audio available on Google cloud platform to Speech-To-Text?

Tags: google-cloud-speech

We are implementing Avaya Google Speech integration, where Avaya IVR platform is capturing user's voice and internally using StreamingRecognize API call to send audio stream to Google Cloud Speech (GCS).

We want to know if there is any feature available in GCS to store the audio (voice input) for every request and access it as per demand.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you use Google Cloud Storage save audio~
google cloud speech only support data logging